# How to tackle 'symbol lookup error' and 'ros::InvalidNameException' on Odroid

Tags: ros, odroid, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run camera calibration on my Odroid U3 running Lubuntu 13.04. I ran the following command :

rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node width:=640 height:=480 frame:=camera device:=/dev/video0

after which a i got an error :

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
what():  Character [4] is not valid as the first character in Graph Resource Name [480].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, / and in some cases ~.
Aborted (core dumped)

running the same command without specifying height and width, i get the following error:

/opt/ros/hydro/lib/uvc_camera/uvc_camera_node: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libimage_transport.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEEb

How do I overcome this problem??

I have followed earlier tutorials successfully and have sourced required files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192550/how-to-tackle-%27symbol-lookup-error%27-and-%27ros::invalidnameexception%27-on-odroid/) by [rookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20074/rookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two issues:

(1) It doesn't look like you're supplying the parameters to the uvc_camera node properly. Private parameters should be prefixed with an `_`. Try:

```
rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node _width:=640 _height:=480 _frame:=camera _device:=/dev/video0
```

(2) It looks like you've picked up the ABI breakage in roslib. Try upgrading everything to the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If apt says that there are "held packages" or "packages not upgraded" then do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20074/rookie/) on 2014-09-12**:
Thanks! the first step didn't work..i tried apt-get update but i got an error:
Failed to fetch http://winswitch.org/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file)
Wont lubuntu upgrade to a higher version and screw up hydro with apt-get upgrade?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-12**:
It looks like you have a winswitch repo configured, but it doesn't support armhf. You should probably remove that from your apt sources and try again.

apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade both install new versions of packages; they don't upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu.

**Comment by [rookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20074/rookie/) on 2014-09-12**:
Thanks, will try this out !